# Best way to juice a pineapple

Tags: pineapple, juicing

What's the best way to juice a pineapple? Should the whole fruit be used or should the core be discarded?

(I'd prefer a method that doesn't require one of those huge electric fruit juicers. The only fruit juicers I have are for oranges and a hand one for lemons.)

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/what-is-the-best-easiest-way-to-juice-a-watermelon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never juiced a pineapple, but I have done a watermelon and I've had some success with a food processor and a cheese cloth.  I'd remove the core of the pineapple, because I don't think there's much juice in it.  Remove the skin as well.  Then run the pineapple through the food processor and pour all of the contents into a cheese cloth over a bowl.  Squeeze all the juice you can out of whatever's in the cheese cloth.

If you don't have a food processor, you can maybe use a cheese grater or potato masher instead.

Comment: A ricer might work well in a pinch too.

Answer (score 8):

To juice a pineapple without a juicer, cut off the rind and remove the fruit from the hard, inner core. Slice it up and pulverize the fruit in a blender or food processor with a few tablespoons of water. Filter through a screen colander if you want a lot of pulp, or line it with cheese cloth if you want less pulp.

[image]

Comment: And the picture is a "screen colander"?

Comment: @adamse: Meh, technically, its more likely to be called a strainer. Colanders are typically bowl-shaped and perforated. There's a bunch of gadgets/strainers specifically shaped for this sort of straining. I'd use a juicer myself but, if I am straining, this is what I have on hand.